# Camera costings for Opportunity/Spirit/Curiosity rovers

Tags: mars, curiosity, camera, opportunity, spirit

I'm currently working on a project investigating the practicalities of a Mars Sample Retrieval rover, as part of my qualification. My area of concern is command/control, and I am struggling to find a rough costing (price) of the camera systems (hazcams and navcams). Does someone have a rough idea of the cost, or a suggestion for where I should look elsewhere?

(I understand that these were bespoke pieces, so the unit costs may not be freely available)

Thanks in advance.